# UIWebview : How to notify UIViewController if any of the already loaded link in the web view fails to open

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, delegates

I have a `UIWebView` controller in which I am loading one `Web Application`. If any of the link inside the web app fails to open, I just need to notify the `UIViewController` that the particular link fails to open and accordingly I need to show the alert box. Can you guys please guide me in this ?? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana : Sorry, but I was actually looking for something else. So far the question I asked, I got the idea from the SO answers. Will definitely upvote.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following `UIWebView` delegate Method

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller write this

In viewdidload

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receivefailedNotification:)
                                             name:@"failedNotification"
                                           object:nil];


- (void) receivefailedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification // this will trig automatically once we provide info to it in webviewcontroller
{
 NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
}
```

In webviewcontroller

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"erroe");
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: erroe forKey:@"OauthoKey"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"failedNotification"
 object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Apple have delegates implemented for all of that: [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

You can use:

`webView:didFailLoadWithError:`
Sent if a web view failed to load a frame.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

**Parameters**

- **webView**: The web view that failed to load a frame.
- **error**: The error that occurred during loading.

**Availability**: Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Remember, you should:

```
yourWebView.delegate = self
```

and

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

or .m

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Called when `UIWebview` failed to load request

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

you can get link that failed from `UIWebview` as follows:

In this method, use this code to get url that failed.

```
NSString *strFailedUrl = UIWebviewObj.request.url.absoluteString;
```

notify your `UiviewController` accordingly or show alert